# How can I create a record with a complex datatype suitable for looping in Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am hoping to move a group of values in a single statement from a row in a table into an object that would be suitable for iteration over.

I have a table that looks like;

```
create table a_table (
field1 varchar2(5),
field2 number(10),
loopnumber1 number(5),
loopString1 varchar2(5);,
loopnumber2 number(5),
loopString2 varchar2(5),
.
.
loopnumber10 number(5),
loopString10 varchar2(5));
```

I would like to create an in memory structure similar to;

```
type loopStuff is record (loopNumber number(5), loopstring varchar2(5));

type my_rec is record (
field1 varchar2(5),
field2 number(10),
loopVar loopStuff(10));

a_rec a_table%rowtype;
temp_rec my_rec;
begin

select * from a_table into a_rec where field1 = something;
temp_rec = a_rec;
or
select * from a_table into temp_rec where field1 = something;
```

Then inside my loop in pl/sql I would set temp_rec = to the incoming record (row) and then be able to process the 10 pairs of fields within another loop. I do not know if this is feasible within Oracle, PL/SQL but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, something like that is possible.  However, always ask yourself if you can perform the same functions with a SQL statement instead.  Usually more efficient.  Your "a_table" looks like it could possibly be further normalized, but can't speculate about the required access, # records, etc.

Comment: I almost put the following in my original post, but didn't because it sounded snarky, and I am asking for help;

"Please don't tell me to normalize the incoming table because I don't have control over it." BTW, I am an old programmer, as well.

Comment: I think @OldProgrammer has a good point.  You don't say if this is for a nightly/weekly batch job, to process 10 rows or 10 million, or what, but you CAN normalize this out (at least get 1 loopnumber/loopstring per row) using UNPIVOT in 11g.  See [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a structure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mytest
AS
   TYPE Loop_Record_Type IS RECORD
   (
      loopnumber   NUMBER (5),
      loopString   VARCHAR2 (5)
   );

   TYPE Loop_Record_Table_Type IS TABLE OF Loop_Record_Type
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


   TYPE A_Table_Record IS RECORD
   (
      field1   VARCHAR2 (5),
      field2   NUMBER (10),
      loops    Loop_Record_Table_Type
   );
END mytest;
```

You can get more details on how to use collections from the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm)

Comment: OK this looks reasonable.  How do I tell it that there are 10 occurrences of Loop_Record_Table_Type?

Comment: PL/SQL collections are dynamic.  You don't need to declare the size ahead of time.  See the doc link, there are examples.

Comment: When I try to set the A_Table_Record = the incoming row from Table_A, the pl/sql compiler tells me the A_Table_Record is the wrong type.

If I change the structure of A_Table_Record to include the 20 fields , instead of "loops" it does not give me an error.

Comment: That is correct. So, you need to just assign the values you want from the result individually to your A_Table_Record.

Comment: I was hoping to define the same structure so that a single copy would move the whole row. Moving a field at a time diminishes the elegance and adds to the line count making it a much less attractive option. I will update my question to clarify this.

Comment: Well, then your record structure must match the query results.  Can't have it both ways.

Comment: If I could define the number of occurrences in the "loops" field in the table as 10, then the structures would be identical. If you are truly an "Old Programmer" you may remember COBOL, and the "REDEFINES", "OCCURS" verbs. That is more or less what I would like.

Comment: I'm not THAT old! :)  I honestly don't know of a way to do that.  Maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: My first language (High School) was Burroughs B200 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3q5n1mR9iM) machine language. The three languages I currently work in are VB.NET, PL/SQL and AS3 (Flex).